# Как объединить аккаунты HashCode и ru.stackoverflow?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow, stackexchange, хэшкод, user-accounts

У меня ранее был акк на `HashCode.ru` (сейчас от него осталась только `math.hashcode.ru`, я как-то пропустил момент когда он объединился с забугорным `stackoverflow`).

Теперь у меня есть аккаунт ещё и здесь (не понятно уже забугорном или не совсем, `stackoverflow`). Создавал я новый аккаунт как рабочий, но в связи с выяснением судьбу `ХэшКод`-а, теперь стал основным.

При попытке добавить к текущему аккаунту старого (что бы объединить их), через `stackexchange` (через диалог `my logins`) ничего не произошло (кроме того, что на текущем аккаунте эта ссылка пропала).
Аккаунты не объединились, хотя в `stackexchange` на старом акке появилась аваторка новой учетки, но в остальном аккаунты остались независимы.

Даже при входе старым акком на `gis.stackexchange` куда я раньше им не входил (так как его не было на ХэшКод) предложило `join this community`, вместо использования текущей аккаунта которым я туда уже заходил.

Как объединить старый акк с новым аккаунтом (не хочется терять вопросы и баллы ни старого, ни нового аккаунтов, и две учетки как бы ни к чему) ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на публикацию «[Как начать пользоваться Stack Overflow на русском, имея учётную запись на ХэшКоде?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24/)».

Comment: Виноват, видимо плохо искал. Попробую запросить объединение. Спасибо.